# css : how to reduce spaces between input elements

Tags: css

I have that

```
<div>
      <input id="clearBtn__id_" username="_id_" type="button" name="clear_btn" class="clear_btn" value="Clear" />
      <input  class="minimize" value="_" type="button">
      <input class="close"  value="x" username="_id_" type="button">
</div>
```

I have like 5 pixels space between each input and I want to set it to 1px.

I tried with margin and padding with no sucess: any clue ?

reagrdfs

Comment: Remove the whitespace between the elements by running the HTML tags together.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the white-space, either you can just take out all the white space between the tags, or simply use `font-size: 0;` on the parent element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8cD/1/) (Removing white space between the elements)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8cD/) (Using `font-size: 0;` on the parent/wrapper element)

---

Note: You can also use `margin-left: -4px;` but I wouldn't recommend to use this as if the parent element has a `font-size` set to [`200%`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8cD/3/), it will again create a white space - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8cD/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the `font-size:0;` trick. It helped me when I had a div set to inline with a button child. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is due to whitespace in your HTML code. There are many CSS tricks but the only **CERTAIN** way to remove whitespace in a displayed page is to... remove it from HTML.

With an HTML comment (and a comment for yourself in 2 months or colleagues or client on why there's a comment: "no whitespace")

```
<div>
      <input id="clearBtn__id_" username="_id_" type="button" name="clear_btn" class="clear_btn" value="Clear" /><!-- no whitespace
      --><input  class="minimize" value="_" type="button"><!-- no whitespace
      --><input class="close"  value="x" username="_id_" type="button">
</div>
```

With list items, you can also put closing tag on next line but that's useless for inputs :)

```
<ul>
      <li>aaa
      </li><li>bbb
      </li><li>ccc
      </li><li>lorem ipsum
      </li><li>dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

You can also close element on next line I believe:

```
<div>
      <input id="clearBtn__id_" username="_id_" type="button" name="clear_btn" class="clear_btn" value="Clear"
      ><input  class="minimize" value="_" type="button"
      ><input class="close"  value="x" username="_id_" type="button">
</div>
```

I'm so accustomed to perfect indentation that I only use the first method...

Answer (score 1):

The white space is caused by the line breaks between each element:

```html
<div>
    <input /> <!-- White Space -->
    <input /> <!-- White Space -->
    <input />
</div>
```

To fix this, there are [quite a lot of options](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). With HTML alone you can simply move all the `input` elements onto one line:

```html
<div>
    <input /><input /><input />
</div>
```

Another option would be to use a bit of CSS to remove the font size from the container:

```css
div {
    font-size:0; /* The white space has no size, therefore isn't visible. */
}

input {
    font-size:16px; /* We restore the font size here. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin and padding will not work because input is an inline element. You have to make input a inline-block or block element to use padding and margin.